# Adding the word "page" to each entry in an index

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm using Word 2010, and I could not find any way to do this.

I am inserting an index at the end of my Word document. It shows the page number fine, e.g., "Zoology, 8".

I would like to add "page" before the page number so that it reads as, "Zoology, page 8".

Is there a way to automate that?

Comment: Search for the INDEX field documentation on the Web and see if the \e switch will do what you need (it might in simple cases but perhaps not when things are more complicated). I would ignore the "5 characters" thing in the documentaiton and check what works on the specific version(s) of Word you need.

Answer (score 0):

Indices are fields in Word. And much like functions in Excel, they have 2 forms, i.e. the formula form and the results form.

For your inserted index, right click and pick `Toggle Field Codes` from the context menu. The field is now in the formula form that may look like this

`{INDEX \c "2" \z "2057"}`

Type right before the closure brackets this string `\e ", page "` that the above formula should be like this

`{INDEX \c "2"  \z "2057"  \e ", page "}`

Now toggle back to the results form by right-clicking the field and picking `Toggle Field Codes` from the context menu.

The final step is to update the field to reveal your changes, so right click and pick `Update Field` from the context menu.

Note: If nothing happened, change the added string from `\e ", page "` to `\e ", p. "`. The string you are inserting with the `\e` switch is very limited in characters so you may need to abbreviate `Page` as `p.` or `pg`.